# Mongoose search returns incorect result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I want to find all documents that contain "user1" in the "fullname" field.
But it's return only "user1" (user10, user11, user123, user111 exist in my db)

---------------RESOLVED-----------------------

```
router.get('', async (req, res) => { 
    const search = req.query.search !=null ? req.query.search : "";
    const page = req.query.page !=null ? req.query.page : 1;
    const limit = req.query.limit !=null ? req.query.limit : 4;
    try {
        User.paginate({$text: {$search: search}}, {page: page, limit: limit, customLabels: myCustomLabels}, function (err, result) {
                console.log(result)
                res.json(result)
        }
        );
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log('Something went wrong:  ', e)
    }
})
```

Model:

```
const {Schema, model, Types} = require('mongoose');
const mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate-v2');

const schema = new Schema ({
    fullname: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    followed: {type: Boolean},
    status: {type: String},
    city: {type: String},
    country: {type: String}
});
schema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);

schema.index({fullname: 'text'});

module.exports = model('User', schema);
```

My request:
    http://localhost:8000/api/user?search=user1

Comment: Please use regex function  searchCond = { name: { $regex: searchText, $options: '-i' } };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex function

```
{ name: { $regex: searchText, $options: '-i' } }
```